# Is it possible to iterate effects in azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-policy

Ask: I would like to know if it is possible to iterate the effects property in azure policy
ex:

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "in": [
                        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                        "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[0].tagName, ']')]",
                                "exists": "true"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[1].tagName, ']')]",
                                "exists": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "modify",
            "details": {
                "roleDefinitionIds": [
                    "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
                ],
                "operations": [
                    {
                        "operation": "addOrReplace",
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[0].tagName, ']')]",
                        "value": "[parameters('tags')[0].tagValue]"
                    },
                    {
                        "operation": "addOrReplace",
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[1].tagName, ']')]",
                        "value": "[parameters('tags')[1].tagValue]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "tags": {
            "type": "Array",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "tags",
                "description": "The tags to apply to the resources."
            },
            "defaultValue": [
                {
                    "tagName": "Environment",
                    "tagValue": "Production"
                },
                {
                    "tagName": "Department",
                    "tagValue": "IT"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

In the above policy I would like to iterate the operation  / addOrReplace multiple times under the "modify" effect , instead of hardcoding like many times like in the policy

```
"operations": [
                    {
                        "operation": "addOrReplace",
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[0].tagName, ']')]",
                        "value": "[parameters('tags')[0].tagValue]"
                    },
                    {
                        "operation": "addOrReplace",
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[1].tagName, ']')]",
                        "value": "[parameters('tags')[1].tagValue]"
                    }
                ]
```

So, basically the requirement for me is to add multiple tags using "addOrReplace" through iteration instead of specifying each instance in the policy definition

Comment: Azure Policy is designed to make decisions based on specified conditions, but it doesn't dynamically generate decisions. In your case, if you want to assign multiple tags to resources, you need to predefine the values in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on the issue, I found that there is no default feature for iteration with the policy definition.

As a workaround, use `referencing` in policy definition. It means that you can create a policy definition for one single tag and reference it for the other tags multiple times. Refer below steps to meet your requirements.

```bash
{
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "in": [
                        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
                        "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                        "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "anyOf": [
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[0].tagName, ']')]",
                                "exists": "true"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "not": {
                                "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tags')[1].tagName, ']')]",
                                "exists": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "modify",
            "details": {
                "roleDefinitionIds": [
                    "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
                ],
                "operations": [
                    {
                        "operation": "addOrReplace",
                        "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
                        "value": "[parameters('tagValue')]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "tagName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "xxx",
                "description": "<TagName>"
            }
        },
        "tagValue": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "displayName": "xxx",
                "description": "<Tagvalue>"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the reference definition file looks in the similar way as below.

```bash
"parameters": {
        "tagName1": {
            "type": "String", //First tag
             },
        "tagValue1": {
            "type": "String",
            },
        "tagName2": {
            "type": "String", //Second tag
             },
        "tagValue2": {
            "type": "String",
         }
    },
    "policyDefinitions": [
        {
            "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/tag1definitionID",
            "parameters": {
                "tagName": "[parameters('tag1')]",
                "tagValue": "[parameters('Value')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "policyDefinitionId": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/tag2definitionID",
            "parameters": {
                "tagName": "[parameters('tag2')]",
                "tagValue": "[parameters('Value')]"
            }
        }
    ]
```